# Extract arithmetic expression from general string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have been trying to extract arithmetic expressions from a general string for quite some time now and I have no clue how to proceed.

```
var reg = /(\(\d+|\d+)((\+|\-|\/|\*|\(|\))(\d+\(*\)*))+/g;
    let result =  message.replace(/\s/g, "").match(reg);
    if(result !== null) {
   for(let i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
   if(areBracketsBalanced(result[i]) || (!result[i].includes("(") && !result[i].includes(")"))) {
if(!result[i].includes("/0")) {
console.log(stringMath(result[i])))
}
```

Where stringMath is a packet that evaluates mathematical expressions in strings and areBracketsBalanced checks if the brackets are balanced. The second clause in the if statement is there because the balance function doesn't check if it doesn't contain parenthesises. However i have noticed that the regex doesn't quite capture everything id like and i have tried to work out how to enable the use of decimal points. I have gotten this but its probably way too complicated and doesn't match everything either:

```
 (\(\d+|\d+|\d+\.\d+|\(\d+\.\d+)((\+|\-|\/|\*|\(|\))(\.*\(*\)*\d*))+(\d*\)*)+
```

The first regex expression doesn't match 34+34(5+5) for instance and the last one is so broken that i wouldn't be surprised if it didn't match anything at all. (2.0+ 1.0001 for instance)

*Is there an effective method for extracting expressions, such as what follows, from generic strings?*

"how do 1 evaluate (0.001*2+2/(1.1/2)(5-1)), but if you don't know how to do that how do I evaluate (-1/9 +    (-3 + 2)(4444444+9.999999))"

The code is meant to extract the instances of arithmetic expressions and log them in the console. In this case 1 is not considered as such an expression.

StringMath is also pretty limited. Is there a way to incorporate the use of exponents as well? Such as "23.001^(-23/44 + 2) - 23(2.0)" I would have tried to define x^y myself by just multiplying x by itself y times and storing that as a string but that doesn't work if y isn't a natural number.

It would have been very convenient if there were a package that handled this but I cant find any.

To be completely exhaustive here is a list of what I consider an arithmetic expression and what I don't:

"()()()(())()(1+1)" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"((((2+2" **CAN** be considered an arithmetic expression if convenient

" 2 ++ 2" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"(2+)2" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"2..2 + 0" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"2x+2" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"2*2 = 4" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

"4" is **NOT** an arithmetic expression

The regex can have a complete disregard for blankspaces, since they are removed prior to its use.

Thankful for help!

Comment: Have you considered that regex is not suitable?

Comment: Maybe "Chomsky type grammar" would be a useful start.